# get list of files names from input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the selected files names from the input element. here is the html element:

```
 <input id="camera-open" type="file" multiple>
```

and here is jquery i am trying to do:

```
    $('#camera-open').change(function(){        
       var names = [];
       $('input[type=file]').each(function(){
       names = $('input[type=file]').val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();    
});
```

But it only gives me one file name! Any idea?

Comment: declare var names[] initially, every time during change it get's initialize to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
//step by step
$( '#camera-open' ).change( function( event ){        
       var fileList = Array.prototype.slice.call( event.target.files );       
       var filePaths = fileList.map( function(file){ return file.name; });
       var onlyNames = filePaths.map( function(file){ return file.split('/').pop().split('\\').pop(); });
       console.log( onlyNames );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising the variables outside the loop,

```
var names = [],
    fileName;
$('#camera-open').change(function(){        
  $('input[type=file]').each(function(){
    fileName = $(this).val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();
    names.push(fileName);
  });
});
console.log(names);
```